# Adding Elements to a List of Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to do the following: Given a function `f[x,y]`, I want to turn the list `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...,{xn,yn}}` into `{{x1,y1,f[x1,y1]},{x2,y2,f[x2,y2]},...,{xn,yn,f[xn,yn]}}`.

In other words, I want to replace each 2-tuple in the original list of lists with a 3-tuple, where the 3rd element is a function evaluated using the 2-tuple. For example, if `f[x,y]` is `x+y`, then I'd want `{{1,2},{5,6}}` to be turned into `{{1,2,3},{5,6,11}}`.

I've seen syntax for many similar tasks, but not one quite like this. I would tremendously appreciate any help -- I've been stumped on this one for a while!

Comment: Hello, wellcome to Mathematica.SE. Try `{##, f[##]}& @@@ list`. And help me find a duplicate in old posts, there is one for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the super speedy help -- I'll try to track down a duplicate. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're wonderful -- thank you so much again :)